# not allowing me to copy file do to files permission

Tags: python-3.x, permissions, windows-7

I have made a program that changes the background picture of my desktop every user defined seconds and there is no problems with that part. However I do have a problem with changing the picture of the log in screen I have set up my computer correctly (*a windows 7 computer*) to change the background picture (*including editing the registry to be able to change the picture more then once*).

I currently changing my login picture manually by moving the picture to a folder I created `C:\windows\system32\oobe\info\backgrounds`. I've chosen to make the task automated using python. I will delete the existing image, copy the new image to the folder and then rename the image to `backgroundDefault.jpg` and repeat every user defined seconds.

To copy, rename, and delete these files using the os module I've tested these steps in my cmd and it works.

Now what seems to be the problem?

Well I'm able to find the folder using `os.path.exists` however I'm unable to copy, delete or rename anything because the program doesn't have permission.

It is also worth noting that I have already tried to give my user permission to write in the folder and I already tried to give the python programme administrator access not only the python program but Py.exe and th pyw.exe that sit in the wondows folder

Is there a way to give the program permission or is there another way of changing the folder that I need to move the files to? Or even is there a different snipit of script I could use to achieve a login background change?

def path_writer_bg():

```
folders_path_bg = input("Please type the folders path of the login background here, then press enter"
                        "\n>")

if os.path.exists(folders_path_bg):

    open("your_path_bg.txt", "w").write(folders_path_bg)

    read_folder_path_bg = open("your_path_bg.txt", "r").read()

    if os.path.exists("task_bg.txt"):

        open("task_bg.txt", "w").write("dir " + read_folder_path_bg + " /s /b >listed_bg.txt")
        file_read_task_bg = open("task_bg.txt", "r").readline()

    else:

        open("task_bg.txt", "w").write("dir " + read_folder_path_bg + " /s /b >listed_bg.txt")
        file_read_task_bg = open("task_bg.txt", "r").readline()

    os.popen(file_read_task_bg)

else:

    input("invalid input. press enter to retry \n")
    path_writer_bg()
```

if os.path.exists("your_path_bg.txt"):

```
read_folder_path_e_bg = open("your_path_bg.txt", "r").read()

open("task_bg.txt", "w").write("dir " + read_folder_path_e_bg + " /s /b >listed_bg.txt")
file_read_task_e_bg = open("task_bg.txt", "r").readline()

os.popen(file_read_task_e_bg)
```

else:

```
path_writer_bg()
```

def everything_bg():

```
with open("listed_bg.txt") as file_bg:
    num_lines_bg = sum(1 for line_bg in open("listed_bg.txt"))
    for num_bg, line_bg in enumerate(file_bg, 1):
        rand_line_bg = random.randrange(num_lines_bg - 1)
        lines_bg = open("listed_bg.txt", "r").readlines()
        open('temp_bg.txt', 'w').writelines(lines_bg[rand_line_bg])
        wallpaper_bg()
```

def wallpaper_bg():

```
path_bg = open("temp_bg.txt", "r").readline()

if os.path.exists("C:\\Windows\\System32\\oobe\\info\\backgrounds\\backgroundDefault.jpg"):
    os.popen("del C:\\Windows\\System32\\oobe\\info\\backgrounds\\backgroundDefault.jpg")

else:
    pass

if os.popen("copy /y" + path_bg + " C:\\Windows\\System32\\oobe\\info\\backgrounds"):
    os.popen("dir C:\\Windows\\System32\\oobe\\info\\backgrounds /s /b >renamer.txt")

else:
    pass

if os.path.exists("renamer.txt"):
    rename = open("renamer.txt", "r").readline()

else:
    pass

    os.popen("rename " + rename + "backgroundDefault.jpg")

wallpaper_bg()
exit()
```

time.sleep(10)
everything()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is because that specific file can't be changed with python due to Microsoft not allowing software to change any file in system32.

Comment: I do agree. I am just looking for an alternative solution or a way to allow the python program to gain permission